# Column visibility - column button not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I dont kow what i am doing wrong but the button column visibiltiy does not appear and there is no error on the console.

Has anybody worked on datatable and buttons?

```
function createTable(data){ 
    alert(data.controlKpiList[0].ASP_NAME +"list");
//  $("#example").dataTable().fnClearTable();
    vtable = $('#example').DataTable({

          'data': data.controlKpiList,
          columns: [
                    { "data": "ASP_NAME" },

                ],

    "columnDefs": [
                   {
                       targets: 1,
                       className: 'noVis'
                   }
               ],
               "buttons": [                   
                                 {
                             extend: 'colvisGroup',
                             text: 'H1',                              
                             hide: [ 2,3 ]                                     
                         } ]
    });
    }
```

Comment: Try the `visible: true` attribute within your `columnDefs` after targets.

Comment: bro, check your `data.controlKpiList ,`